# RVM doesn't symlink to /usr/bin

Tags: ruby, path, rubygems, textmate, rvm

some time ago I've installed [RVM](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/) and now my current ruby path is

```
$ which ruby
/Users/marcos/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p249/bin/ruby

$ which gem
/Users/marcos/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p249/bin/gem
```

but some bundles in textmate still asking for something like `/usr/bin/env ruby` so in results it says that gems aren't installed.

so my question is, is there any way to symlink my current ruby to this default one I'm not sure if rvm can do that automatically as well because I wouldn't want to change it again if I install or change to other ruby version from RVM.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried [rwillian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/164552/rwilliams) alternative but it seems very complex and difficult to replicate. So what I did was just leave it or use the --system default installation for RVM at that moment.
Its was an easier, quicker alternative and fixed my problem.